# How to parse two or more arguments after a option using getopt in Python?

Tags: python, getopt

I'm using getopt in Python now and know some basic usage.
But I wonder if there is way to parse two or more arguments after a option.

e.g.

```
python test.py -a 111 -b 222 333
```

How to get both '222' and '333' when I parse option '-b'.Actually I can only catch '222'.

Comment: Use CSV and split when you parse? 222,333

Comment: @tehjoker Yeah, it's a solution to add additional characters. Maybe getopt doesn't include the method I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use argparse (why optparse, why?):

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', action='append')
>>> parser.parse_args('--foo 1 --foo 2'.split())
Namespace(foo=['1', '2'])
```

From the documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

eg:

```
python test.py -a 111 -b 222 -b 333 -b 4444
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameter 'nargs' can do that in argparse.

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs=2)
>>> parser.add_argument('bar', nargs=1)
>>> parser.parse_args('c --foo a b'.split())
Namespace(bar=['c'], foo=['a', 'b'])
```

e.g.

```
python --foo 111 222
```

[argparse documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs)